# Orbitals without overlaps in band structures of solids

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory, density-functional-theory

We know every band in the band structure of solids is the result of overlaps of an orbital type. My question is that when there is not any overlap between a type of orbitals(which may be the lowerest energy subshells such as 1s), how the eigenstates corresponding to these orbitals appear in band structure?
I don't know there is any real example of this situation. I just want to know what will be the result if we apply this assumption to for example DFT-based simulators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If orbitals are not interacting then the energy band will look like a line in the band structure, as exemplified by the following diagram:
[image]

I was not able to find any journal published examples, but [this tutorial](http://exciting-code.org/carbon-electronic-structure-calculations) on electronic-structure calculations with a DFT solver shows how for the non-interacting low free energy electrons of silver, bands look like straight lines:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If there is no hamiltonian matrix element between such orbitals then the bandwidth vanishes.

Comment: So, these states don't appear in the output. Is there any real example of it?

Comment: These bands should appear as a single line in the band structure.

Comment: So, the related band is a vertical line. Is it true?

Comment: It is independent of momentum. If momentum is on your y-axis then yes.